# embed php dropdown box in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I want to embed this a drop down list populated from a db query :

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost', 'blahh', 'password');
mysql_select_db('reporting');

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT ProductNumber, Description FROM Stock WHERE ProductGroup ='800'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='PRODS' multiple>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['Description'] . "'>" . $row['Description'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

?>
```

Into this javascript which creates multiple rows when a button is pressed.

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Add Items To Repair</title>
<script language='javascript'>
row_no=0;
function addRow(tbl,row){
row_no++;
if (row_no<=20){
if (row_no>=10){
var textbox  = row_no+'.)<input type='text' size = '2'  maxlength= '2' name= quantity[]>';}
if (row_no<10){
var textbox  = row_no+'.  )<input type='text' size = '2'  maxlength= '2' name= quantity[]>';}
var textbox2 = '<input type='text' size = '100' maxlength= '100' name= desc[]>';
var textbox4 = '<input type='text' size = '20' maxlength= '20' name= issue[]>';
var tbl = document.getElementById(tbl);
var rowIndex = document.getElementById(row).value;
var newRow = tbl.insertRow(row_no);
var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
newCell.innerHTML = textbox;
var newCell = newRow.insertCell(1);
newCell.innerHTML = textbox2;
var newCell = newRow.insertCell(2);
newCell.innerHTML = textbox3;
var newCell = newRow.insertCell(3);
newCell.innerHTML = textbox4;

}
if (row_no>12){
alert ('Too Many Items. Limit of 12.'); 
}
}


</script>
```

I essentially want to add the drop down box into the javascript created.
I'm very basic at javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using above method i would suggest you to use clone method of jQuery.

Ex: put all the form elements in a container as :

```
<div id="container1">
    <input type='text' size = '2'  maxlength= '2' name= quantity[]>
    <input type='text' size = '100' maxlength= '100' name= desc[]>
    <input type='text' size = '100' maxlength= '100' name= issue[]>
    <select name=selectbox[]>
        <option>You can loop here from your DB call</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="container2">
</div>
```

After this use

```
$( ".container1" ).clone().appendTo( ".container2" );
```

More reference here :

```
http://api.jquery.com/clone/
```

to use this onclick go as following ex :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".clicktoappend" ).click(function() {
        $( ".container1" ).clone().appendTo( ".container2" );
    });
});
```

PS : Not tested but this should work

Above is an example and not tested yet, check if this helps.

Comment: sorry can you tell me how i can automate this via onclick. is this possible?

Comment: i have provided an ex to use this onclick, please check